# NewLine in Java Manifest

Tags: java, jar, manifest

I would like to put newlines in a property value of a manifest.  Its for some custom property fields for our project.  Is there a way to specify a new line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The escaped character "\n" will specify a newline.